# Odoo 10 - Qweb t-if t-else syntax

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I do not know which is the right syntax for if-else in qweb.

```xml
<t t-if="origin != l.origin">
  <td>foo</td>
<t t-else/>
  <td>bar</td>
</t>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `<t t-else=""><td>bar</td></t>`, take a look the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/qweb.html#reference-qweb-conditionals).

Answer (score 4):

In above lines you have closed else tag  **`<t t-else/>`**

You should write as following :

```xml
<t t-if="origin != l.origin">
  <td>foo</td>
</t>
<t t-else="">
  <td>bar</td>
</t>
```

Answer (score 2):

You also try t-elif :

```xml
<t t-if="origin != l.origin">
    <td>foo</td>
</t>
<t t-elif="">
    <td>bar</td>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note for those who are looking for similar problem, `t-else` is only added in Odoo 10.

So, for Odoo < 10, negation of `t-if` should be used instead.

```
<t t-if="condition">
</t>
<t t-if="not condition">
</t>
```

For Odoo >= 10,

```
<t t-if="condition">
</t>
<t t-else="">
</t>
```